# Does Win10 keeps a record of deleted files?

Tags: windows-10

I'm missing a folder in my Win10 machine and I don't remember if it was me that deleted the folder. I don't care about the folder contents but I need to be sure that it was me who delete it. Does Win10 keep a registry of deleted files or actions done by the logged user related to the file system?

Comment: Unless you have auditing enabled, windows can't tell you who deleted the folder.

Comment: Windows has sophisticated permissions/authentication systems wherein you can set things up so such unwanted file actions will be prevented.

Answer (score 0):

No it does not keep a record by default. You can turn on File and Folder Auditing, but that is not retroactive - just going forward. Once done Auditing should tell you.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

> To complete this procedure, you must be signed in as a member of the
> built-in Administrators group or have Manage auditing and security log
> rights.
>
> To apply or modify auditing policy settings for a local file or folder
>
> Select and hold (or right-click) the file or folder that you want to
> audit, select Properties, and then select the Security tab.
>
> Select Advanced.
>
> In the Advanced Security Settings dialog box, select the Auditing tab,
> and then select Continue.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To set up auditing for a new user or group, select Add. Select Select
> a principal, type the name of the user or group that you want, and
> then select OK. To remove auditing for an existing group or user,
> select the group or user name, select Remove, select OK, and then skip
> the rest of this procedure. To view or change auditing for an existing
> group or user, select its name, and then select Edit. In the Type box,
> indicate what actions you want to audit by selecting the appropriate
> check boxes:
>
> To audit successful events, select Success. To audit failure events,
> select Fail. To audit all events, select All.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder is still found in the Recycle Bin, then the column of
"Date Deleted" can tell the day and minute of the deletion.

From the date and time, you might be able to figure out who used the computer
at the specified time.